# What could be the reason these wires need to be connected outside of the sensor?

Tags: schematics

Below diagram shows the inner system of a wind-meter and four output wires to power it and collect the 4-20mA output signal as current or voltage by using a resistor.

[image]

I verified with a voltmeter's continuity test that the wire gn and bn in the diagram are connected to together innerly as expected from the diagram.

But I don't understand why they need to be shorted at outside of the device as well. I put a yellow question mark indicating the location. What could b e the reason bn and gn are connected at outside since they are already connected inside??

Comment: You still hold more cards then anyone reading this question.

Comment: Convenience, you don't need to join multiple wires together, you can have two distinct lines coming for your 4 to 20, and two distinct lines for power, and ground them back at your panel.

Comment: @MadHatter I dont understand what you mean. Are you saying the connection where the yellow question mark is unnecessary or? If that connection does not exist the negative terminals of 4-20 and the power supply are already connected inside the sensor. That is confusing me why there is two connection foe 4-20 return and power ground. Why would I " ground them back at your panel"?? they are already grounded. inside arent they?